# SAS - Assign field as content of another Field

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset like this:

Fields: `A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 | INDEX | B`
...

The `INDEX` field contains a variable name: A1 or A2 or ... or A6

I want `B` to have the content of the field which is in the `INDEX` field.

How do I dynamically assign the field `B` as the field specified in the `INDEX` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fairly easy way to solve this is to use arrays and VNAME.

```
data have;
input a1 a2 a3 index $;
datalines;
1 2 3 a1
2 3 4 a2
3 4 5 a3
4 5 6 a1
5 6 7 a3
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
array as a1-a3;
do _t = 1 to dim(as);
 if upcase(vname(as[_t])) = upcase(index) then b = as[_t];
end;
run;
```

You can add a LEAVE statement in that if (make it a if... then do block) if you have a very large array to improve performance.

Comment: That's not a valid SAS variable name.  If that is the variable _label_, then you can use VLABEL instead of VNAME.

Comment: I understand Joe, The only problem is that my field is "BU Node Level N Long Name" with N from 1 to 29.
B has "BU Node Level 14 Long Name" for example.
How can I use arrays in this case and work with long named fields?
thanks

Comment: The example should work exactly as is, except swapping VNAME for VLABEL.  If you want to more easily write the array statement, you can use:  `array vars BU_Node_Level:;` (or however your actual variable names are structured), or even `array vars _numeric_;` to just check all numeric variables, if that isn't too many excess variables (it shouldn't mismatch any, since it only will do something if it finds one that matches correctly).